# Passing parameters in Http request body while opening Webpage simultaneously

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, http-post, url-routing

I have Windows Phone application in c#. I need to open a web page and simultaneously pass the url with some parameters in the body of the form via http post. I think the way I am currently attempting to do this is wrong and insecure. As i am basically  using a webbrowser control and just navigating to the url which is converted from a string. below is an example of the string I convert to a url.

```
   private string CreateUri()
   {
       string baseurl = string.Format(locatorurl + "?req={0}&lat={1}&long={2}",srcname,
            location.Lat,location.Long);

       return baseurl;
   }
```

then I just call

```
 webbrowser.Navigate(new Uri(baseurl,URIKind.Absolute))
```

what i need to do is pass params in a http post to the url AND simultaneously open the page the url points to but i dont know how to add these params to the body to be honest. I've seen plenty of posts using a webclient but none are doing what I am trying to do. Is it even possible? any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to go back to the basics of what is an HTTP request and how it does work. basically, "opening a page" as you say is a `GET` method, which is different from a `POST`, but you still can pass variables in both cases. It is actually not clear to me what you're eventually trying to achieve.

Comment: what iam trying to achieve is 1. pass params to a url that consumes the params. 2. open the webpage in a webbrowser so it is viewable

Comment: basically http post in a browser

Comment: there's usually an HTTP GET before a POST in a browser : 1) You display the page with the form (usually a GET request, then browser displays the response) 2) You send the form (usually a POST) 3) Browser displays the response body from the POST request. What I'm not sure if you understood is that you can totally pass params through a GET, that's actually what you're doing in the code above.

Comment: i know iam passing the parameters in the uri. just wasnt sure if it was the most secure way of doing it? so your saying i grab the plain url (without params) first. then post to the page once  it has returned in the browser. okay thanks

Comment: You didn't talk about security in your original post... GET parameters  can be found back in browser history while POST aren't. That said, when passed over a non-secured connection, both are totally accessible if someone is sniffing the network. If you need to pass sensible data, you need an https connexion. As I still don't know what you're trying to achieve as functionality, it's hard to give advice or be sure if you need a POST or not...

Comment: i need to pass a url params and also view the  page of that url. probably need to pass a password in one of the params. I hope this is understandable

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626636%28v=vs.105%29.aspx  i think this is what i was looking for.